GPIB addressing in terms of bytes sent out on the bus
I'm trying to update a very old piece of kit that sits on a GPIB by using a new processor (old one is obsolete and we have no source code). It's very simple in terms of the number of commands it needs to support, I have to write some firmware that runs on an STM32 to interpret the bytes that come in on the bus and act, if the message is for this unit.
I understand how the physical lines work, how commands are delimited by CR/LF or EOI, I can see how I should read the message in byte-by-byte using the handshaking lines and have a complete message to decode.
I think I can understand how some messages will be for all nodes that sit on the bus and it's clear that you should only respond to some messages if they are sent to your address. What, even after ploughing through many, many tutorials I do not understand (or at least am unsure about) is where, in a complete message, is the address sent.
I'm further confused by an article that says all multiline messages use the DIO lines with:
bit 7 = Parity
bit 6 = CG1
Bit 5 = CG0
Bits 4-0 - Command/address information

And then goes on to list address commands such as MLA, MTA, LADx, UNL etc. With these I can see how some of them work, I think, and I have seen an example "Hello World" message as below:
Mnemonic/Hex Code/Comment
        
UNL      3F      puts any current listener back into idle state
LAD 1    21      addresses the device at primary address 1 as listener          
MTA      55     controller addresses itself as talker (address 21 = hex15)      
DAB 'H'  48     the controller sends the data string to the device (ASCII codes)
DAB 'E'  45     
DAB 'L'  4C          
DAB 'L'  4C      
DAB 'O'  4F      
DAB ' '  20      
DAB 'W'  57      
DAB 'O'  4F 
DAB 'R'  52      
DAB 'L'  4C      
DAB 'D'  44      
DAB 0D   0D          send CR character (hex 0D)
DAB 0A   0A         send LF character (hex 0A)      
UNT      5F          the controller untalks itself
UNL      3F     // unaddresses all listeners on the bus

This message has three of these "commands" and then the "hello world" in ASCII section plus CR/LF, then two more of these "commands".
How does the receiver know when the commands are stopping and the message is starting? Is it simply the ATN line that determines this?  Do I need to process all bytes received as these command types if ATN is low and then, when ATN is high, know it is the "message", ie what the unit has to parse if its address matches what is in command section when ATN is high? On the one hand this would seem obvious, but I have seen other articles which suggest you have command messages and data messages which to me suggests a start character, some info and then CR/LF - giving a complete message for either data or command type messages.
If it's not the ATN line that determines this, how do you know when you're going from address commands to device-specific messages sent as ASCII data?
As I type this message out I wonder whether I'm getting confused between what I would consider a command (such as "I0L0M0 CR LF" - which is one of the commands in the manual of the unit whose processor I am updating) with data. Maybe, in GPIB parlance, command is purely those bytes than come in when CMD is low and data when CMD is high whereas GPIB data is the  command that is carried out by the unit if its address matches what is in the GPIB command bytes?
In other words, is it in fact that in GPIB parlance "I0L0M0 CR LF" is data, and in terms of the local unit language, the GPIB data is the message (command) specifying what the local unit has to do?
